# Remove an empty line at the end of a file (bash)

Tags: bash, file, sed, terminal, line

How do I remove empty lines the end of the file? I've tried multiple combinations of `sed` and this is my current attempt. Would it be possible to remove the empty line at the end without using `awk`?

```
printf "" > "temp.txt" #erases any current values in temp.txt
for num in "${myarr[@]}" #the value from the array was taken from a file with an empty line at the end as well
do
    echo $num >> "temp.txt" #writes new values in new line
done
sed '/^$/d' "temp.txt"
```

The way it's different from the suggested duplicate is that I'm using

```
for var in "${@:3}"
do
    filename=${var}".txt"
    cut -d ',' -f "$var" mycsv.csv > "$filename"
done
```

to write to the file, so I can't control what gets written into the file as easily as in a while-loop

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$` as the address to match last line:

```
sed '${/^[[:space:]]*$/d;}' temp.txt
```

**Edit:**

The `[[:space:]]*` matches the line if it contains spaces or tabs.

To edit the file in place, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i.bak '${/^[[:space:]]*$/d;}' temp.txt
```

The original file will be saved here with a `.bak` extension.

You can also redirect output to a new file:

```
sed '${/^[[:space:]]*$/d;}' temp.txt > newtemp.txt
```

Comment: I'm getting a `sed: 1: "${/^$/d}": extra characters at the end of d command` error when I surround the regex with single-quotes and a `sed: 1: "${/^$/d}": extra characters at the end of d command` error when I surround the regex with double-quotes

Comment: Try: `sed '${/^$/d;}' file`

Comment: Thank you for the response! The code runs, but there's still an empty line at the end of the file

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm running this code as a script

Comment: @stumped, empty line, you mean a line break(newline) , right?

Comment: @stumped: Are you trying to remove multiple empty lines from end of file?

Comment: There is just one empty line at the end of the file, so I''m only trying to remove one

Comment: @stumped Last line might contain spaces or tabs. I edited.

Comment: When I type the code in, it outputs to the console the result with no empty new lines. But when I view the file, it has the empty new line at the end

Comment: Fixed: I used `echo` for all the elements except last in the array then used `printf` for the last element

Comment: Because normal output of sed is to `stdout`(your terminal). See my update to edit the file in place.